# Can I configure Cognito to set access_token cookie on parent domain?

Tags: cookies, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront

I have a setup similar to this:

A site at: site.company.com

A CDN at:   cdn.comapny.com

I'm using Cognito for easy social login.
Cognito sets my OAuch access token cookie to: site.company.com (which is expected), but I want to read it from cdn.company.com (yes I need authorization there).

What would you suggest, is the best thing to do to achieve this?

Do I need to change domains on the site and/or the CDN maybe (so that the site is on company.com for example)?
Or can I "tell" Cognito to set the cookie to the TLD somehow?

Thanks in advance.